# Handling Ajax request using PhantomJS

Tags: html, phantomjs

I'm unable to capture ajax  in button click using PhantomJS. I have a web page,in which there is a textbox and button. In web page, if any body enter a product name and click on button then a ajax request is executed and get top 100 Product sell to customer list.

But when i try to capture the webpage using PhantomJS, I'm unable to get ajax data in screenshot as well as in return page content.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open("localhost://mywebsite/Product.html", function (status) {
if (status === "success") {
    //console.log('Successfully');
    page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
    page.render("before_submit.png");

    page.evaluate(function () {
        $('#txtProduct').val('TCS');
        $('#btnGet').click();
    });
});
    page.render("after_submit.png");
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    console.log('Unable to connect');
}
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct `localhost://mywebsite/Product.html`

Comment: Yes, I had deploy the application in my local IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested, page.open requires url protocol, so you have to add **http://**

```
page.open("http://localhost://mywebsite/Product.html", ...
```